# Generate a binary column by searching values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
dict1={'TA':{'MA':8.8,'BA':8.8,'CA':1.3,'DA':1.4,'RA':1.5 },
   'GA':{'MA':1.1,'BA':1.2,'CA':8.8,'DA':8.8,'RA':8.8 },
   'RA':{'MA':4.1,'BA':5.2,'CA':4.5,'DA':1.8,'RA':1.2 },
   'SA':{'MA':9.2,'BA':1.1,'CA':1.3,'DA':8.8,'RA':8.8 }}
 df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1,orient="index")
```

I have a data frame

```
      MA  BA  CA  DA  RA   
  TA 8.8 8.8 1.3 1.4 1.5    
  GA 1.1 1.2 8.8 8.8  8.8   
  RA 4.1 5.2 4.5 8.8  1.2   
  SA 9.2 1.1 1.3 8.8  8.8   
  
  #Expected data_frame in output
     MA  BA  CA  DA  RA   New_Column
  TA 8.8 8.8 1.3 1.4 1.5    1
  GA 1.1 1.2 8.8 8.8  8.8   0
  RA 4.1 5.2 4.5 8.8  1.2   1
  SA 9.2 1.1 1.3 8.8  8.8   1
```

Is there anyway to generate the New_Column from this above input data frame. If the count of value 8.8 is less than equal to 2 in any row then its value would be 1, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x : 1 if sum(x == 8.8) <= 2 else 0, axis = 1)
df

    MA  BA  CA  DA  RA  new_column
TA  8.8 8.8 1.3 1.4 1.5 1
GA  1.1 1.2 8.8 8.8 8.8 0
RA  4.1 5.2 4.5 1.8 1.2 1
SA  9.2 1.1 1.3 8.8 8.8 1
```